# Selecting a CSS element by attribute(s) [plural!]

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I've been using CSS3 selectors to select specific elements based on their attributes, although today, I have programmed myself into a corner, where I need a select a specific element based on the presence of TWO different attributes, instead of only 1.

e.g. I need to select the first div.

```
<div data-foo="bar" data-bar="baz">
<div data-foo="bar" data-bar="lorem">
<div data-foo="ipsum" data-bar="baz">
```

Just for fun, I tried `div[data-foo="bar", data-bar="baz"]`, but not surprisingly, that didn't work.

Is there any way for me to get that specific element?

Right now, the only solution I can think of is to select all elements with the correct `data-foo` attribute, and then loop through the results to find the element with the correct `data-bar` attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close, it's:

```
div[data-foo="bar"][data-bar="baz"]
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ofumuh)

From the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

> Here, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "hello" attribute has exactly the value "Cleveland" and whose "goodbye" attribute has exactly the value "Columbus":
>
> `span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }`

(There's a new [CSS3 Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) as well, which is increasingly supported, but we don't need CSS3 features for this.)

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks for the link! I mustn't've been reading the spec closely enough. **Edit**: Hm, it seems to be absent from the CSS3 spec. That's a little annoying, since the rest of the functionality is documented...

Comment: @JulianH.Lam: No worries, glad that helped. It's in the CSS3 specification as well: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors It's the same example, but the paragraph starts with a new sentence actually *saying* that they're supported rather than just demonstrating it: *"Multiple attribute selectors can be used to represent several attributes of an element, or several conditions on the same attribute."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it possible to select like input[type="text"][type="email"]. I want to apply the same style to both text and email types.

Comment: @Geethanga: `input[type="text"][type="email"]` wouldn't match anything (because the same element can't have both `text` and `email` for the `type` attribute), but you can do `input[type="text"], input[type="email"] { /* ...your styles here.... */}`.